# ProcessBuilder increase handle counts when it execute

Tags: java, windows, memory-leaks, handle, processbuilder

I got a problem when i execute ProcessBuilder in Java JDK 1.7 in Windows 7 64. I found that the handle count is increasing  When i checked the Windows Task Manager.  Thread count didn't increase.  I tried in the JDK 1.8 also. But it had same problem. I tried many source sample from web. so that It increase only one handle now. But I coudln't decrease the last handle until now. I have been trying to find the way to solve this everywhere.  But I couldn't find. Is there anybody know how to solve this problem? Please check below source.

[Windows task manager example]
name      /PID  /userName /CPU /handle (open files) /thread
javaw.exe /10388  /XXX    /00  /1038                /   47

I have an experience about "too many open files" problem in the Linux. I solved it by changing the source it occured. So that I checked it in the Windows also. I think it is problem if the handle count increase forever. My customer gave me the exe (jar) program. So I have to call the program each time to send SMS message. I am worried the handle will increase many so that OS memory resource lack will be occured. 
(* i changed my below source by Guillaume F's advice. )

```
boolean sendYn = false;
Process p = null;
try {
    String process_string = "";

     List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
     commands.add(sBatchName);
     commands.add(sTelphon);
     commands.add(sMessage);

     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
     p = pb.start();//** handle increse 4

     input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
     while ((process = input.readLine()) != null) {
            if(process.equals("[send_success]")){
                //sucess
                sendYn = true;
                process = null;
                break;
            }else {
            //fail 
                sendYn = false;
                process = null;
                break;
            }
    }   
    //input.close();// decrease one
    //input = null;
    //int result = p.waitFor();

    p.getErrorStream().close();// decrease one 
    p.getInputStream().close();// decrease one
    p.getOutputStream().close();//decrease one 
    //p.destroy();

}catch(Exception e1){

    //if(input != null){
    //  input.close();  
    //}

    if(p != null){
        p.getErrorStream().close();
        p.getInputStream().close();
        p.getOutputStream().close();
    }

} finally {
    p.waitFor();
    p.destroy();
}
```

Comment: I'm curious: why do you need to keep the handle count steady? Does your code break when it changes or something?

Comment: @Nzall Depending on the OS, leaving such "system resources" unclosed can become a problem. In earlier times, on other OSes, I have seen systems crash because they ran out of filehandles.

Comment: And what is issue here? New process requires more resources from OS.

Comment: @GhostCat : on Windows, unless you allocate global resources (eg. ATOM) they are cleaned up when process exited.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/27248/what-is-a-process-handle

Comment: I think Linux is stable for this. Windows is trouble. I don't know about Windows handle perfectly. But i think it will make problem becuase my application will call the Customers application many time everyday.  Do you know how close the process perfectly?

Comment: destroy P in a finally. Windows deals with handles just as well as Linux does. Also you close the inputstream two times, which can definitely trigger the exception.

Comment: Hi.  Guillaume F.   I added p.destroy() in the finally {} .  But it is same.  It increase 1 handle still.

Comment: I found some strange when I tried above source.  the handle count increase to 1500 , then it changed from 1500 to 1100 after that.  It  started the handle count from 1100 again.  It repeats again and again. Does it mean it is stable?